# Volume of clothes. Or volume in clothes?

Tags: prepositions

I was just wondering which is correct out of these:

> The more boutiques, the more demand for volume *of* clothes.

Or

> The more boutiques, the more demand for volume *in* clothes.

Comment: It depends on what you’re trying to say. What are you trying to say?

Comment: To expand on the above question, "volume" might refer to trading in volume (large quantities per transaction), or simply to an overall increased demand for clothes regardless of the size of each transaction.